# php select field count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table. It is having some columns: f1t, f2t,...to...f18t.
And I have $id = 4. So I want to count f?t where they = $id.
Maybe f2t, f10t and f15t = $id. So the count will be 3

How can I make it?
I tried:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT (
(f1t = \"".$id."\")+
(f2t = \"".$id."\")+
(f3t = \"".$id."\")+
(f4t = \"".$id."\")+
(f5t = \"".$id."\")+
(f6t = \"".$id."\")+
(f7t = \"".$id."\")+
(f8t = \"".$id."\")+
(f9t = \"".$id."\")+
(f10t = \"".$id."\")+
(f11t = \"".$id."\")+
(f12t = \"".$id."\")+
(f13t = \"".$id."\")+
(f14t = \"".$id."\")+
(f15t = \"".$id."\")+
(f16t = \"".$id."\")+
(f17t = \"".$id."\")+
(f18t = \"".$id."\")
) AS totalCount FROM ".TB_PREFIX."fdata WHERE vref = ".$_SESSION['wid'];
$sql1 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo "<br>".$sql1;
```

Thanx

Comment: Not clear. Share sample output.

Comment: @AT-2016 I mean I want to get count of columns that equals 4

Comment: Which column exactly and what's 4?

Comment: Count is used to count rows not columns, indeed your question is quite confusing.

Comment: `$id = 4` and the fields is: f1t, f2t ... to ... f18t. If f1t and f2t = 4 so $count = 2 because we have 2 columns that equal 4.

Comment: Do you want get count across all rows  or for a particular row?

Comment: How's that f1t and f2t = 4? Can you explain?

Comment: In the table's columns I have f1t If I select the row I will get `$row['f1t'] = 4` and the same for some columns that = 4. I want to get count to `$row['f?t']` that = 4. Clear?

Comment: see up now maybe it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on so far what I've understood.*

You need to use `+` to get the `count`.

**In order to get occurrence of `4` in the columns `f1t .... f8t` for all rows**

```
SELECT 
( 
    (f1t = 4)+
    (f2t = 4)+
    (f3t = 4)+
    (f4t = 4)+
    (f5t = 4)+
    (f6t = 4)+
    (f7t = 4)+
    (f8t = 4)
) AS totalCount
FROM your_table
```

[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83003/1/0)

**Note:**

Since MySQL boolean expression resolves into `0/1` so that you can use this in your case.

Note that `(a=b) returns 1 only if a is equal to b otherwise it returns 0`

---

**TEST:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `your_table`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `your_table`;
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  f1t INT,
  f2t INT,
  f3t INT,
  f4t INT,
  f5t INT,
  f6t INT,
  f7t INT,
  f8t INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of your_table
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('1', '2','3','4','4','1','8','4','9');
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('2', '2','8','1','5','4','8','4','9');
______

SELECT 
*
FROM your_table;

| id | f1t | f2t | f3t | f4t | f5t | f6t | f7t | f8t |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   4 |   1 |   8 |   4 |   9 |
|  2 |   2 |   8 |   1 |   5 |   4 |   8 |   4 |   9 |
```

Running the query given above on this set of data you will get the following output:

**output:**

```
| totalCount |
|------------|
|          3 |
|          2 |
```

---

**Suggestion:** Normalize your data

Comment: I did it. But I got this `Resource id #177`

Comment: Didn't understand. Please explain.

Comment: When I print $sql I get `Resource id #177` and 177 is not fix

Comment: I mean I don't get a number.

Comment: I don't know what you tried, do I? Please share what you have tried

Comment: '$sql2 = "SELECT (
(f1t = \"".$id."\")+
(f2t = \"".$id."\")+
(f3t = \"".$id."\")+
(f4t = \"".$id."\")+
(f5t = \"".$id."\")+
(f6t = \"".$id."\")+
(f7t = \"".$id."\")+
(f8t = \"".$id."\")+
(f9t = \"".$id."\")+
(f10t = \"".$id."\")+
(f11t = \"".$id."\")+
(f12t = \"".$id."\")+
(f13t = \"".$id."\")+
(f14t = \"".$id."\")+
(f15t = \"".$id."\")+
(f16t = \"".$id."\")+
(f17t = \"".$id."\")+
(f18t = \"".$id."\")
) AS totalCount FROM ".TB_PREFIX."fdata WHERE vref = ".$_SESSION['wid'];
$sql1 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo "<br>".$sql1;'

Comment: share the value of `$sql2` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this cannot be done, you should change the structure of your table so that  f1t, f2t ... to ... f18t will be rows. Then you can easily do it with the count operator.